# c++ standard library list usage?

Tags: c++, dbx

Porting a program from linux to solaris, building it with solarisstudio 12.3.

It has these definitions:

```
typedef std::list<ISocketMultiplexerJob *> CSocketJobs;
typedef CSocketJobs::iterator CJobCursor;

CSocketJobs   m_socketJobs;
```

and this code:

```
CSocketMultiplexer::CJobCursor
CSocketMultiplexer::nextCursor(CJobCursor cursor)
{
    CLock lock(m_mutex);

        CJobCursor j = m_socketJobs.end();
        CJobCursor i = cursor;
        while (++i != m_socketJobs.end()) {
            if (*i != m_cursorMark) {   // CRASHES HERE!!
                j = i;

                // move our cursor just past the job
                m_socketJobs.splice(++i, m_socketJobs, cursor);
                break;                                                  
             }
        }
        return j;
  }
```

It crashes  at the line indicated above because:

```
(dbx) print i
i = {
    _C_node = (nil)
}
```

It looks like the "++i" iteration traipsed off the list but the test against
m_socketJobs.end() failed to see it and let it go through.  Need help debugging, eg how can I analyze *i in dbx in a more c++-aware fashion?

The caller of nextCursor() is in this snippet, <>:

```
                // collect poll entries
                if (m_update) {
                       m_update = false;
                       pfds.clear();
                       pfds.reserve(m_socketJobMap.size());

                       CJobCursor cursor    = newCursor();
                       CJobCursor jobCursor = nextCursor(cursor);
                       while (jobCursor != m_socketJobs.end()) {
                               ISocketMultiplexerJob* job = *jobCursor;
                               if (job != NULL) {
                                    pfd.m_socket = job->getSocket();
                                    pfd.m_events = 0;
                                    if (job->isReadable()) {
                                            pfd.m_events |= IArchNetwork::kPOLLIN;
                                    }
                                    if (job->isWritable()) {
                                            pfd.m_events |= IArchNetwork::kPOLLOUT;
                                    }
                                    pfds.push_back(pfd);
                               }                               
                               jobCursor = nextCursor(cursor);  //FATAL CALL
                       }
```

And here's the function newCursor():

```
CSocketMultiplexer::CJobCursor
   CSocketMultiplexer::newCursor() {  
     CLock lock(m_mutex);
     return m_socketJobs.insert(m_socketJobs.begin(), m_cursorMark);
}
```

I did some munging around and found that newCursor()/nextCursor() sorta works and doesn't work.... maybe another thread is hurting the context.  In the example below (embedded in my program) the first init of "CJobCursor c = newCursor();" is robust, I can insert the line "c= nextCursor(c);" anywhere in my program and it doesn't crash.   But the next one
 with the comment "BAD" is flawed and crashes on the second nexCursor() call.
I find this interesting but no explanation yet. I think I need to continue testing
inside the whole program because the context is killing things. What do you think?

```
void
CSocketMultiplexer::serviceThread(void*)
{
    std::vector<IArchNetwork::CPollEntry> pfds;
    IArchNetwork::CPollEntry pfd;

                    CJobCursor c    = newCursor();
                    CJobCursor j = nextCursor(c);
                    c = nextCursor(c);
                    c = nextCursor(c);

    // service the connections
    for (;;) {
            CThread::testCancel();

            // wait until there are jobs to handle
            {
                    CLock lock(m_mutex);
                    while (!(bool)*m_jobsReady) {
                            m_jobsReady->wait();
                    }
            }

            // lock the job list
            lockJobListLock();
            lockJobList();

            // collect poll entries
            if (m_update) {
                    m_update = false;
                    pfds.clear();
                    pfds.reserve(m_socketJobMap.size());

                    CJobCursor cursor    = newCursor();  //BAD, Ill-fated object
                    CJobCursor jobCursor = nextCursor(cursor);
                    c = nextCursor(c);
                    cursor = nextCursor(cursor);        // SEGV's here
                    while (jobCursor != m_socketJobs.end()) {
                            ISocketMultiplexerJob* job = *jobCursor;
                            if (job != NULL) {
                                    pfd.m_socket = job->getSocket();
                                    pfd.m_events = 0;
                                    if (job->isReadable()) {
                                            pfd.m_events |= IArchNetwork::kPOLLIN;
                                    }
                                    if (job->isWritable()) {
                                            pfd.m_events |= IArchNetwork::kPOLLOUT;
                                    }
                                    pfds.push_back(pfd);
                            }                               
                            c = nextCursor(c);
                            jobCursor = nextCursor(cursor);
                    }
                    c = nextCursor(c);
                    deleteCursor(cursor);
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure `i` is valid when the function starts? `++i` would be undefined behaviour if it's not dereferenceable (although I'm not sure why the condition would be false in that case)

Comment: Yes, I have printed out i and j repeatedly while stepping through the program, including stepping into the list code, but the c++ "stuff" is opaque compared to standard C that I'm used to.  What is _C_node anyway. Also, the "++i" in the splice() line is something you wouldn't do in standard C.

Comment: `_C_node` is a pointer to a list node, and it's null, so the iterator does not point to a valid element of the list (and is not the past-the-end iterator either). _"I have printed out i and j repeatedly"_ doesn't tell me that `i` is actually a valid iterator. You could have complete garbage and print it out.

Comment: @StuartKreitman I tried to recreate your code using dummy classes.  So far, I didn't get an error:  See here: http://codepad.org/ElVhColQ  Maybe you can add code to this to duplicate your scenario?  One thing is that you're using pointers, and who knows what could be going on with your real program w.r.t the pointer usage.  My example at the link is simple and safe (forgetting about the obvious memory leak at the end).  Also, *DO_SOME_STUFF* in your post will always be suspicious.  Please post what this "stuff" is.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I posted the "stuff".  Also, I should have mentioned that I'm trying to build this in -m64.  The 32bit mode has the same error.

Comment: @StuartKreitman - What's confusing is the incrementing twice of `i` in your function.  You pre-increment it in the `while` loop, and then you increment it again in the call to `splice` within the `while` loop.  The code is hard to follow and frankly, very easy to make a mistake with two increments potentially being done.  My advice is to drop the preincrement for now and increment `i` explicitly when it needs to be incremented.

Comment: @StuartKreitman - ok, I see you have a `break` statement after the splice, so that should not be a problem.  Still, the preincrement of `i` in a while loop is unorthodoxed.  I still suggest you write the loop in a way that looks like the "traditional" while loop, i.e. the iterator starts at a position, and at the end of the loop, it gets incremented to the next item.

Answer (score 1):

> It looks like the "++i" iteration traipsed off the list

No, I think it looks like an invalid iterator (maybe default constructed), not a past-the-end iterator.

A `std::list<T>::iterator`  needs to be able to decrement backwards through the list again, so it can't point to null, otherwise once you reached the end and it became null you couldn't go backwards again. Typically a past-the-end `std::list` iterator has to point to a sentinel node.

So your `i` does not point to any element of `m_socketJobs` which means that `m_socketJobs.end()` is not reachable from `i` no matter how many times you increment it, so `i != m_socketJobs.end()` is *always* going to be true.

Try adding `assert( i != CJobCursor() )` to the top of the function and I bet it aborts there, because I think you've called the function with an invalid iterator.

You should not assume that just because `(++i != m_socketJobs.end())` is true the iterator is dereferenceable.

Comment: Isn't it possible that `cursor == m_socketJobs.end()`, so when the `while` conditional is evaluated, `++i` causes `i` to be invalid before the equality check is executed?

Comment: i is declared/initialized in the 4th line of the function

Comment: @StuartKreitman, yes, but it's just a copy of `cursor` so check that `cursor` is valid before you start incrementing it or dereferencing it.

Comment: @sdzivanovich, yes it's possible, I don't know what the Solaris standard library does if you try to increment a past-the-end list iterator. It might set it to null. That's undefined behaviour, so anything could happen.

Comment: Basically there's nothing else you can do to _"analyze *i in dbx in a more c++-aware fashion"_ because by the time it crashes it's too late, `i` is not a valid iterator. Period. You need to examine the value of `cursor` when the function starts. Compare it to `m_socketJobs.end()` **before** you increment it. Compare it to `CJobCursor()`. Your function assumes it will be passed a valid iterator, and apparently that isn't true. Look at the callers, see why they are passing invalid iterators and if the fix needs to be in the caller, or whether `nextCursor` needs to handle that case safely.

Comment: snippet of the caller:   
    CJobCursor cursor    = newCursor();
    CJobCursor jobCursor = nextCursor(cursor);
    while (jobCursor != m_socketJobs.end()) {
                                   ISocketMultiplexerJob* job = *jobCursor;
                                   if (job != NULL) {
                                           DO_SOME_THINGS;
      }                               
                                  jobCursor = nextCursor(cursor);                           }

Comment: @StuartKreitman - Please add that to your question, not as a comment.  Also, when you fix this problem, go back to your "working" linux version, because it's also broken.

Comment: And show the code of `newCursor()` too, since that seems to be the source of the invalid iterator.

Comment: I sprinkled "assert( i != CJobCursor() )"  all over the place. It didn't trap anything

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I'm going offline for a few (dinner time in PST)

Comment: @jonathan, Since list is doubly linked, shouldn't I be able to call cursor = nextCursor(cursor) infinitely?

Comment: Just because it's doubly-linked doesn't mean it's circular. It has a beginning and an end.